# Open android app on NFC and consume NFC tag

Tags: android, cordova, nfc

Developing a PhoneGap android app.

I have an app that on open requires NFC for authorization. I can open the app by tapping a NFC tag to the android phone by making an

```
 <intent-filter>.
```

When the app opens you must tap your tag again to authorize. Is there a way to consume the NFC tag when you open the app via NFC tap, to authorize as well?

Comment: No idea, but I'd love to see an answer. You might wanna try it on http://android.stackexchange.com/ tho!

Comment: Thanks just posted there.
http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/106502/open-android-app-on-nfc-and-consume-nfc-tag

Comment: @Paramone Android Enthusiasts is for [end-user questions](http://android.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) about Android. This is the proper site for development questions.

Comment: @eldarerathis Correct indeed, my apologies. I thought that even tho it's regarding development rather than end-user questions, he'd still get an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Supposing that your NFC tag is using the NDEF technology, then you can use the similar way to consume the full dispatching information as the below code. the primary work to parse the intent and extract the information you want.

```
@Override  
protected void onResume() {  
    super.onResume();  

    if (NfcAdapter.ACTION_NDEF_DISCOVERED.equals(getIntent().getAction())) {  

        Tag tag=getIntent().getParcelableExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_TAG);  
        Ndef ndef=Ndef.get(tag);  

        try {  
            ndef.connect();  
            NdefRecord ndefRecord=createTextRecord(data,Locale.US,true);  
            NdefRecord[] records={ndefRecord};  
            NdefMessage ndefMessage=new NdefMessage(records);  
            ndef.close();
        } catch (IOException e1) {  
            e1.printStackTrace();  
        } catch (FormatException e) {  
        }          
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use the [phonegap-nfc plugin](https://github.com/chariotsolutions/phonegap-nfc) you can handle the NFC tag scanned in the intent.

Add a [nfc.addMimeTypeListener](https://github.com/chariotsolutions/phonegap-nfc#nfcaddmimetypelistener) to your code. Read the NDEF data from the tag and authenticate the user. Note that the NFC scan from the intent filter is sent as a [ndef-mime event](https://github.com/chariotsolutions/phonegap-nfc#nfcevent) regardless of the actual tag type.

For an example of this see https://github.com/don/nfc-launch